# Python: Removing characters from a string and then returning it

Tags: python, string, list

For example, given a list of strings `prices = ["US$200", "CA$80", "GA$500"]`,
I am trying to only return `["US", "CA", "GA"]`.

Here is my code - what am I doing wrong?

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    prices = ""
    list = prices.split()
    list.remove("$")
    "".join(list)
    return list
```

Comment: you're initialising `prices` to `""`, overriding it's value

Comment: You posted a single string, but called it a "list of strings".  Please clarify?

Comment: You say that you want only the two-letter abbreviations, but you go out of your way to include the integer amount (after you remove the dollar sign).  Which do you need?  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: Don't use the variable name `list`, you're redefining the inbuilt `list`.

Answer (score 2):

Since each of the strings in the `prices` argument has the form `'[country_code]$[number]'`, you can split each of them on `'$'` and take the first part.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    return [p.split('$')[0] for p in prices]
```

So `get_country_codes(['US$200', 'CA$80', 'GA$500'])` returns `['US', 'CA', 'GA']`.

Also as a side note, I would recommend against naming a variable `list` as this will override the built-in value of `list`, which is the type `list` itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code, and you have to fix all of them to make it work:

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    prices = ""
```

Whatever value your caller passed in, you're throwing that away and replacing it with `""`. You don't want to do that, so just get rid of that last line.

---

```
    list = prices.split()
```

You really shouldn't be calling this list `list`. Also, `split` with no argument splits on spaces, so what you get may not be what you want:

```
>>> "US$200, CA$80, GA$500".split()
['US$200,', 'CA$80,', 'GA$500']
```

I suppose you can get away with having those stray commas, since you're just going to throw them away. But it's better to split with your actual separators, the `', '`. So, let's change that line:

```
    prices = prices.split(", ")
```

---

```
    list.remove("$")
```

This removes every value in the list that's equal to the string `"$"`. There are no such values, so it does nothing.

More generally, you don't want to throw away any of the strings in the list. Instead, you want to *replace* the strings, with strings that are truncated at the `$`. So, you need a loop:

```
    countries = []
    for price in prices:
        country, dollar, price = price.partition('$')
        countries.append(country)
```

If you're familiar with list comprehensions, you can rewrite this as a one-liner:

```
    countries = [price.partition('$')[0] for price in prices]
```

---

```
    "".join(list)
```

This just creates a new string and then throws it away. You have to assign it to something if you want to use it, like this:

```
    result = "".join(countries)
```

But… do you really want to `join` anything here? It sounds like you want the result to be a list of strings, `['US', 'CA', 'GA']`, not one big string `'USCAGA'`, right? So, just get rid of this line.

---

```
    return list
```

Just change the variable name to `countries` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is structured where the first two characters are the county code you can use simple string slicing.

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    return [p[:2] for p in prices]
```

Answer (score -1):

You call the function sending the prices parameter but your first line initialize to an empty string:

prices = ''

I would also suggest using the '$' character as the split character, like:

list = prices.split('$')

try something like this:

```js
def get_country_codes(prices):
    list = prices.split('$')
    return list[0]
```

Comment: This is just going to return `'US'`, not `['US', 'CA', 'GA']`.